# Akka Remote on Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.StackTraceElement[].clone()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, akka

I'm working on a simple Android app which should connect to a server in the same local network. Both the server and app run Akka Remote.

Indeed it is possible to start the ActorSystem in the Android app, but with the first request to the server the below listed NullPointerException appears.

It does not matter if I start the ActorSystem in the main thread or in an AsyncTask and funnily enough the problem does not exist on the emulator but only on a physical device in a "real network".

Has anyone an idea what the cause of this problem could be?

```
06-05 14:07:35.074 4746-5303/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: [INFO] [06/05/2016 14:07:35.073] [AsyncTask #7] [Remoting] Starting remoting
06-05 14:07:35.544 4746-5303/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: [INFO] [06/05/2016 14:07:35.543] [AsyncTask #7] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://clientActorSystem@192.168.254.104:12345]
06-05 14:07:35.547 4746-5303/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: [INFO] [06/05/2016 14:07:35.546] [AsyncTask #7] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://clientActorSystem@192.168.254.104:12345]
06-05 14:07:35.589 4746-5235/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat D/login-tag: Send login request... 192.168.254.105:14711
06-05 14:07:35.821 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: [WARN] [06/05/2016 14:07:35.819] [clientActorSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-5] [akka.tcp://clientActorSystem@192.168.254.104:12345/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FChatServerSystem%40192.168.254.105%3A14711-0] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://ChatServerSystem@192.168.254.105:14711] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.StackTraceElement[].clone()' on a null object reference] 
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: [ERROR] [06/05/2016 14:07:35.832] [clientActorSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6] [Remoting] Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.StackTraceElement[].clone()' on a null object reference
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.StackTraceElement[].clone()' on a null object reference
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.OnlyCauseStackTrace$class.fillInStackTrace(AkkaException.scala:27)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.remote.EndpointException.fillInStackTrace(Endpoint.scala:113)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:106)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:60)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:59)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.AkkaException.<init>(AkkaException.scala:15)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.remote.EndpointException.<init>(Endpoint.scala:113)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException.<init>(Endpoint.scala:153)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$initializing$1.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:596)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:437)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
06-05 14:07:35.838 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
06-05 14:07:35.839 4746-5305/ch.fhnw.ws6.chat I/System.out:     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```